# How to config credential to login a website successfully using requests in python3?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to bypass login to following site using python3 requests module. I have tried with maintaining cookies, also using with & without session.
But I am not getting the page appears after login.

Visit the below source, then right-click and select Translate to English option. Then enter below credential and click on submit.

**Source** - https://igrsup.gov.in/igrsup/userServicesLogin?request_locale=hi

**Id -** 'shreeram'

**pass -** 'Shreeram@1'

This is the password encryption script saved as **encrypt.py** which can be used directly by importing it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18-ebQwr-P6b7O-xD4K9M3r7I63Nwx31X/view

Following is the main script importing above encrypt.py

```
# For requests
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re

# For Pass encryption
import encrypt

# For image processing
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

def get_soup(resp_content):
    return BeautifulSoup(resp_content, 'lxml')

def get_hidden_inputs(soup):

    if soup is None:
        return None

    data = {}
    hidden_inputs = soup.find_all("input", {"type": "hidden"})
    if hidden_inputs:
        for input_key in hidden_inputs:
            if input_key.has_attr('value'):
                data[input_key['name']] = input_key['value']
            else:
                data[input_key['name']] = ''
    return data

def parse_image(img_response):
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_response.content))
    text = image_to_string(img)
    return text

def get_captcha_text(resp):
    image_resp = kscrapy_obj.get('https://igrsup.gov.in/igrsup/CaptchaImageAction',cookies= resp.cookies)
    print(image_resp)   
    return parse_image(image_resp)

def get_salt_value(soup):
    raw_salt = soup.find('script',text=re.compile('var salt')).text
    salt_value = re.findall('[a-z0-9]{16}',raw_salt)[0]
    return salt_value
```

> Creating session & fetching login page

```
sess = requests.session()

# Login Page (phase-1)
resp = sess.get('https://igrsup.gov.in/igrsup/userServicesLogin?request_locale=hi')
print(resp)
```

> Fetching captcha image

```
img_header = {'Accept': 'image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8',
 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'Host': 'igrsup.gov.in',
 'Referer': 'https://igrsup.gov.in/igrsup/userServicesLogin?request_locale=hi',
 'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"',
 'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
 'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'image',
 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'no-cors',
 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

# Captcha request (phase-2)
image_resp = sess.get('https://igrsup.gov.in/igrsup/CaptchaImageAction', headers = img_header, cookies = resp.cookies)
print(image_resp)   
captcha_text = parse_image(image_resp)
print(captcha_text)
```

> Fetching hidden inputs and encrypting password

```
resp_soup = get_soup(resp.content)

# Get hidden inputs
input_data = get_hidden_inputs(resp_soup)

# Get salt value
input_salt = get_salt_value(resp_soup)
input_salt

# Password encrytion
pass_word = 'Shreeram@1'
login_pass = encrypt.PyJsHoisted_hash_sha_(pass_word,input_salt)
print(login_pass)

# Updating input parameters
data = {'login_id': 'shreeram',
'login_password': login_pass,
'enteredCaptcha': captcha_text,
'label.log_in': 'प्रवेश करें',
       }

data.update(input_data)
print(data)
```

> Sending post data to get after login page

```
post_headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'Content-Length': '352',
 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 'Host': 'igrsup.gov.in',
 'Origin': 'https://igrsup.gov.in',
 'Referer': 'https://igrsup.gov.in/igrsup/userServicesLogin?request_locale=hi',
 'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"',
 'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
 'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
 'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36,'}

# Submit Login detials (phase-3)
resp2 = sess.post('https://igrsup.gov.in/igrsup/us_secureIgrsUserLogin',data = data, headers = post_headers, cookies = resp.cookies) 
print(resp2)

with open(html_out.html,'wb+') as f:
    f.write(resp2.content)
```

The output of last response i.e resp2 is 200, however on successful login the status code of resp2 should be 302. So when we open the saved html response, it shows the same login page with error as invalid inputs. I feel like some where cookies are being used differently. As when we try to login on browser with same credentials it works perfectly. Can someone please help me to find a way to get it done.

Comment: Try persisting the session with [requests.Session](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/).

Comment: @baduker Hi, I've tried with that as well, still not getting required output.